# Count Total Number of List Items in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

How to count Total Number of List Items in a ListView ?

I am writing a Church Application in which i am populating list using images stored into SD Card, but now i want to count total number of list items.

```
     // to upload whole list
     for(int position = 0; position < lstView.getAdapter().getCount(); position++)
                 {
                     flags.put(position, true);   
                 }

                 ((BaseAdapter) lstView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();        
            }
        });

        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        listSDCardImages = fetchSDCardImages();

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listSDCardImages);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ListSDCardImagesAdapter(this));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total number of Items are:" + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Everytime i am getting **0**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Total list view count is

```
 lstView.getAdapter().getCount() ,
```

So use

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total number of Items are:" + lstView.getAdapter().getCount() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: thanks solved i did stupid mistake, may i know how to assign this value to String variable (to show in a TextView), and i will accept your answer after 5mins as per SO rule

Comment: Yes, why not  String count = ""+lstView.getAdapter().getCount();              textView.setText(count);

Comment: In ListView i am using two different images in many list items using red circle and many list items using blue, so what i have to do if i want to count list items contains red circle and list items those contains blue circle, check this : http://pastebin.com/ENWcQSmM

Comment: pastebin.com is not opening, please use other site

Comment: I am using getView with holder:                          if(strExist)
{
         holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
}
         else
{
         holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue);
}

Comment: The correct way to parse numbers to String is String.valueOf(lstView.getAdapter().getCount());

Comment: one simple of doing is : public int countRed = 0;
public int countBlue = 0;


 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // inflate view
  
 if(strExist) 
{
 holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red); 
 countRed++;
}
 else
 { holder.statusImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue); } 
 countBlue++;

 
 }