# how to get the number of list items in a listview

Tags: android, listview

my code shows user apps in a listview. I want to show the total number of list items (apps) in my textview. how do i get the number?

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_listview, results){


//  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results ) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
             TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
             //Change this to your drawable
             Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
             textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( myDrawable , null, null, null);
             return textView;
        }
};  
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: please correct the language tag

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript

Comment: I corrected the tag, sorry for your loss

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708271/count-total-number-of-list-items-in-a-listview

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the variable "results" which you use to construct your adapter, is a "List" object, right? Then, if you use the code below:

```
int totalNumber = results.size();
```

Then, the variable **totalNumber** will be a int equal to the number of items on your list.

Alternatively, as Kevin.Lam said, you can also try to use

```
adapter.getCount();
```

to return the total number of items.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly by using ArrayAdapter's getCount() method - it shows "How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter"