# Can't get the count of the list item getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am getting the error NullPointerException i already try the method mention

**[Count Total Number of List Items in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708271/count-total-number-of-list-items-in-a-listview)**

but no luck i want to get the items in list

This is what i am doing

```
    int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
```

**Custom Adapter code**

```
package com.example.wildstone.cv_maker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by wildstone on 08/02/2018.
 */

public class Custom_Adapter_for_Language extends ArrayAdapter<Language_data_comes_here>
{
    Context context ;;

    public Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Context context, ArrayList<Language_data_comes_here> array) {
        super(context,0 , array);

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {


        View v = convertView ;

        if (v == null){

            v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_view ,parent ,false);


        }

        Language_data_comes_here language_data_comes_here = getItem(position);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_image_display_list_item);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_text_display_list_item);

        textView.setText(language_data_comes_here.getLanguage());
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.language);



return v ;
    }
}
```

**activity main**

```
package com.example.wildstone.cv_maker;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Language_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView listView ;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton ;
   Custom_Adapter_for_Language arrayAdapter ;
    ArrayList<Language_data_comes_here> arr ;
    Toolbar toolbar ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_);



        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button);
        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.plus);
        floatingActionButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Language_Activity.this);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater() ;

                View view  = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.enter_language , null);
                final EditText language = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.language_entered);

                toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                toolbar.setTitle("  Add Language !");
                toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.language);

                Button add_language = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.enter_language);


                add_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        arr.add(new Language_data_comes_here( R.mipmap.language , language.getText().toString()));

                        arrayAdapter = new Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Language_Activity.this , arr);

                        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                        language.setText("");

                    }
                });



                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setView(view);

                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create() ;
                alertDialog.show();





            }
        });




        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                arr.remove(position);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        }) ;



getListCount();





    }


    public void getListCount () {

        int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
        Button bb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);

        switch(count){

            case 1 :
                bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There is 1 item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                break ;
            case 2 :
                bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There is 2 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                break ;
            case 3 :
                bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There is 3 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            case 4 :
                bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There is 4 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                break ;
            case 5 :
                bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There is 5 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                break ;
            case 6 :
                bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There is 6 items", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


                break ;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(Language_Activity.this, "There list is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break ;
        }



    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
02-14 22:03:13.736 25664-25664/com.example.wildstone.cv_maker D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-14 22:03:13.739 25664-25664/com.example.wildstone.cv_maker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.wildstone.cv_maker, PID: 25664
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wildstone.cv_maker/com.example.wildstone.cv_maker.Language_Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.wildstone.cv_maker.Custom_Adapter_for_Language.getCount()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.wildstone.cv_maker.Custom_Adapter_for_Language.getCount()' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.wildstone.cv_maker.Language_Activity.getListCount(Language_Activity.java:117)
                                                                                    at com.example.wildstone.cv_maker.Language_Activity.onCreate(Language_Activity.java:106)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: You should not be setting `listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` in an `onClickListener()`. You should be setting this as early as possible within `onCreate()` and then accessing the adapter accordingly later on.

Comment: Better still, take a look at using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the "What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?" @MichaelDodd i just understand why this problem occur .Will be careful in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array adapter is null until add_language button is clicked.  But getListCount() method is getting called from onCreate.

You might need to change initialize arrayAdapter in onCreate before the getListCount method. The following lines should outside of the onClickListener.

```
    arrayAdapter = new Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Language_Activity.this , arr);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Something like this onCreate Method:-

```
     arr = new ArrayList<>();
     arrayAdapter = new Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Language_Activity.this , arr);
     listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

And in click listener, you just have to notify dataset

```
     add_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                     .
                     .
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks .It solved my problem

Comment: Happy coding @SaadZahoor

Answer (score 0):

```
            add_language.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    arr.add(new Language_data_comes_here( R.mipmap.language , language.getText().toString()));

                    arrayAdapter = new Custom_Adapter_for_Language(Language_Activity.this , arr);

                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    language.setText("");

                }
            });
```

This creates a new adapter each time you click the button. If the user does not click the button before trying to count the number of elements in the adapter, you will get the NPE.

To fix this, you should create a single adapter in `onCreate()`. Then when you add elements to the `ArrayList`, just call [`notifyDataSetChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()).